# exclude Array of DateInterval from Array of DateInterval

Tags: swift, dateinterval

I want to exclude Array of `DateInterval` from Array of `DateInterval`. This's my code, but I don't think it will not be helpful.. it goes in infinite loop sometimes and I couldn't solve it.

```
extension DateInterval {

    static func exclude(_ excludedIntervals: [DateInterval], from periods: [DateInterval]) -> [DateInterval] {
        if excludedIntervals.isEmpty { return periods }
        var resultSlots: [DateInterval] = []

        for period in periods {
            let results = period.exclude(excludedIntervals)
            resultSlots.append(contentsOf: results)
        }

        return resultSlots
    }

    func exclude(_ execludedIntervals: [DateInterval]) -> [DateInterval] {
        if execludedIntervals.isEmpty { return [self] }
        var sortedExecludedIntervals = execludedIntervals.sorted()
        var resultSlots: [DateInterval] = []
        var execludedInterval = sortedExecludedIntervals.removeFirst()
        // remove execludedIntervals from self
        if let intersection = self.intersection(with: execludedInterval) {
            if self.start == intersection.start && self.end > intersection.end {
                let newSlot = DateInterval(start: intersection.end, end: self.end)
                resultSlots.append(contentsOf: newSlot.exclude(sortedExecludedIntervals))
            } else if self.start < intersection.start && self.end == intersection.end {
                let newSlot = DateInterval(start: self.start, end: intersection.start)
                resultSlots.append(contentsOf: newSlot.exclude(sortedExecludedIntervals))
            } else if self.start < intersection.start && self.end > intersection.end {
                let preSlot = DateInterval(start: self.start, end: intersection.start)
                resultSlots.append(contentsOf: preSlot.exclude(sortedExecludedIntervals))
                let postSlot = DateInterval(start: intersection.end, end: self.end)
                resultSlots.append(contentsOf: postSlot.exclude(sortedExecludedIntervals))
            } else {
                // start = start && end = end
                resultSlots = []
                return resultSlots
            }
        }


        return resultSlots
    } 
}
```

For example, I want to exclude 1 pm- 3pm and 5 pm - 6 pm intervals from an interval 12 pm - 6pm. The function should return 12 pm - 1 pm and 3 pm - 5 pm.

Comment: You say "I want to exclude Array of DateInterval from Array of DateInterval." What does that mean? You want to exclude every interval in the `execludedIntervals` array from the intervals in the array periods? And what do you mean by exclude? If I have an interval that goes from Monday to Friday of this week, and I want to exclude an interval from Wednesday to Thursday, does that mean that the result is an interval from the beginning of Monday to the end of Tuesday, followed by an interval that is just Friday? (breaking the interval of all weekdays into 2 different, discontinuous intervals.)

Comment: @DuncanC yes exactly, and if I want to exclude  1 pm- 3pm, 5 pm - 6 pm intervals from 12 pm - 6pm. The function should return 12 pm - 1 pm and 3 pm - 5 pm. I am building this function for reservation system

Comment: You should edit your question to better explain what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of thoughts:

1. If I want a method to operate on an array of `DateInterval`, I’d suggest putting it in an `Array` (or `Sequence`) extension, constrained to `DateInterval` types, rather than a `static` method on `DateInterval`:

   ```
   extension Array where Element == DateInterval {
       func exclude(_ excludedIntervals: [DateInterval]) -> [DateInterval] { ... }
   }
   ```
2. When considering excluding a `DateInterval` from another, there are tons of different scenarios:

   - You could exclude some small window from the middle of the interval;
   - You could exclude a portion at the start of the interval;
   - You could exclude a portion at the end of the interval; and
   - You could exclude the whole interval.

   In my mind, it gets too messy to think of all of those scenarios, so I decided to simplify this a bit and decide:

   - Where exactly does the excluded region intersect with the current interval (and `DateInterval` supplies a nice method to do that for us);
   - If I “cut out” that intersection from the date interval, I might end up with two intervals, a `before` interval and an `after` interval (e.g. if I cut 2pm-3pm out of noon-6pm, the `before` interval will be noon-2pm and the `after` interval will be 3pm-6pm);
   - The algorithm then distills down to “if the interval is intersected by the excluded region, replace the original interval with the two other intervals, the one before and the one after”; and
   - Given that I’m mutating the original array of resulting intervals, I’d suggest nested loops, with the outer loop being the intervals to be excluded and the inner loop being the resulting intervals which, because it’s mutating, I’ll iterate through using a `while` statement, manually checking and adjusting the current `index`.

That yields:

```
extension Array where Element == DateInterval {
    func exclude(_ excludedIntervals: [DateInterval]) -> [DateInterval] {
        var results: [DateInterval] = self

        for excludedInterval in excludedIntervals {
            var index = results.startIndex
            while index < results.endIndex {
                let interval = results[index]
                if let intersection = interval.intersection(with: excludedInterval) {
                    var before: DateInterval?
                    var after: DateInterval?

                    if intersection.start > interval.start {
                        before = DateInterval(start: interval.start, end: intersection.start)
                    }
                    if intersection.end < interval.end {
                        after = DateInterval(start: intersection.end, end: interval.end)
                    }
                    let replacements = [before, after].compactMap { $0 }
                    results.replaceSubrange(index...index, with: replacements)
                    index += replacements.count
                } else {
                    index += 1
                }
            }
        }

        return results
    }
}
```

Then we can consider the exclusion applied to a single `DateInterval` as just a special case of an array with one item:

```
extension DateInterval {
    func exclude(_ excludedIntervals: [DateInterval]) -> [DateInterval] {
        return [self].exclude(excludedIntervals)
    }
}
```

So:

```
let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()

let start = formatter.date(from: "2019-02-09T12:00:00Z")!
let end = formatter.date(from: "2019-02-09T18:00:00Z")!

let exclude1Start = formatter.date(from: "2019-02-09T13:00:00Z")!
let exclude1End = formatter.date(from: "2019-02-09T14:00:00Z")!

let exclude2Start = formatter.date(from: "2019-02-09T16:00:00Z")!
let exclude2End = formatter.date(from: "2019-02-09T17:00:00Z")!

let intervals = DateInterval(start: start, end: end)
    .exclude([
        DateInterval(start: exclude1Start, end: exclude1End),
        DateInterval(start: exclude2Start, end: exclude2End)
    ])

print(intervals)
```

Will produce:

```
[
    2019-02-09 12:00:00 +0000 to 2019-02-09 13:00:00 +0000,
    2019-02-09 14:00:00 +0000 to 2019-02-09 16:00:00 +0000,
    2019-02-09 17:00:00 +0000 to 2019-02-09 18:00:00 +0000
]
```

Comment: Thanks @Rob for your answer but could you please add more comments? I would like to understand how you have implemented the function.. thanks

Comment: @DotFreelancer - I’ve clarified my answer, outlining my thought process...

Comment: @Rob Congrats on reaching 300K.  Btw very nice answer. Follow up on it  https://github.com/leodabus/DateInterval-Subctration/blob/master/RangeReplaceableCollectionDateInterval.swift

Comment: @LeoDabus - That’s a good generalization of the above. I always think it’s good to extensions on the applicable protocol. Nicely done!